# Parsing json with Python, need only one info from JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing

Code:

```
import requests

url = "https://website..."

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer 00D8E0064aixxVOXbvvwarbgTiJz....',
  'Cookie': 'BrowserId=euYL0ekf5A...'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Result:

```
{"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Lead","url":"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q8E000StUAM"},"Id":"00Q8E034008pPStTAM"}]}
```

I need just that **Id** from this JSON response. I expect it would be something like

```
print(response.text[Id])
```

but that's not working for me. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `response.json()` to parse JSON response into dict. Then `records` is a list, suggesting there may be multiple records. Iterate over items in the list:

```
ids = [record.get('Id') for record in response.json().get('records', [])]
```